# How I can save a page to Wayback Machine?

Tags: json, api

I checked their API documentation and didn't find anything useful that gives me the ability to create snapshots of the URLs I choose.

Answer (score 0):

Submitting a POST request to the root path (https://pragma.archivelab.org) with JSON data containing url (String) and annotation (Object) fields will save a snapshot of url using the Wayback Machine and store the annotation object, making a bidirectional link between the stored snapshot and annotation entries.

Here's an example of such a request:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"url": "google.com", "annotation": {"id": "lst-ib", "message": "Theres a microphone button in the searchbox"}}' https://pragma.archivelab.org
```

Comment: Dude, I want the API.